# How to determine the importance of variables in different regression models

Tags: regression, importance

I have two different regression models developed from two different datasets as follows:

Y1 = B0*X1+B1  , R2 = 0.16

Y2 = C0*X2+C1  , R2 = 0.34

Y1 and Y2 are representing the same measure but they have different values

X1 and X1 are different features.

How I can compute the importance (contribution) independent variable in each model?

Comment: In case `X1` and `X2` are two different features, I suggest you create a single regression model containing both features `X1` and `X2`. The p-values give you then an indication on the contribution of each feature.  If `X1` and `X2` are the same features, the result of the model is due to the split of the dataset.

Comment: X1 and X2 are different features from different datasets and cannot be entered in the same model.

Comment: 1) Think about what you mean by 'importance' and look at other questions in the tag that you have used. 2) Be careful about using p-values to quantify this (I would not use them). 3) Having 2 predictors, models and datasets does not change anything about your question, which is basically "How do I quantify importance in any regression?"

Comment: e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/422769/feature-importance-for-linear-regression

Comment: @Reinstate Mocnica
Thank you 