# In a mixed-effects model (e.g., fitted with `lmer()`) - how can I tell which predictor is more important/useful/meaningful?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, importance

When fitting a mixed effects model, how can I tell which variable is more *meaningful* (or *important*)?

This is a follow-up question on [how to tell which variable is more meaningful when modeling the relationship between several predictors and outcome variable](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/540341/271660). Whereas the linked question dealt with linear models fitted with `lm()` function in `R`, the strategies provided there don't work with mixed effect models (e.g., fitted with `lmer()` from `{lme4}`).

Let's consider a minimal reproducible example in `R`:

```r
library(lme4)
#> Loading required package: Matrix

my_model <- lmer(weight ~ Time * Diet + (1 | Chick), data = ChickWeight)
summary(my_model)
```

which gives

```r
#> Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
#> Formula: weight ~ Time * Diet + (1 | Chick)
#>    Data: ChickWeight
#> 
#> REML criterion at convergence: 5466.9
#> 
#> Scaled residuals: 
#>     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
#> -3.3158 -0.5900 -0.0693  0.5361  3.6024 
#> 
#> Random effects:
#>  Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
#>  Chick    (Intercept) 545.7    23.36   
#>  Residual             643.3    25.36   
#> Number of obs: 578, groups:  Chick, 50
#> 
#> Fixed effects:
#>             Estimate Std. Error t value
#> (Intercept)  31.5143     6.1163   5.152
#> Time          6.7115     0.2584  25.976
#> Diet2        -2.8807    10.5479  -0.273
#> Diet3       -13.2640    10.5479  -1.258
#> Diet4        -0.4016    10.5565  -0.038
#> Time:Diet2    1.8977     0.4284   4.430
#> Time:Diet3    4.7114     0.4284  10.998
#> Time:Diet4    2.9506     0.4340   6.799
#> 
#> Correlation of Fixed Effects:
#>            (Intr) Time   Diet2  Diet3  Diet4  Tm:Dt2 Tm:Dt3
#> Time       -0.426                                          
#> Diet2      -0.580  0.247                                   
#> Diet3      -0.580  0.247  0.336                            
#> Diet4      -0.579  0.247  0.336  0.336                     
#> Time:Diet2  0.257 -0.603 -0.431 -0.149 -0.149              
#> Time:Diet3  0.257 -0.603 -0.149 -0.431 -0.149  0.364       
#> Time:Diet4  0.254 -0.595 -0.147 -0.147 -0.432  0.359  0.359
```

Although I included both `Time` and `Diet` (and their interaction) as predictors, I still want to know which of them is more *meaningful* in terms of explaining the outcome variable `weight`. In other words, if someone were to force me to use only one predictor in my model, which one should I choose?

Answer (score 1):

A similar approach to those in the linked question can be used.  Here is an example using the `domir` package.

```
> library(domir)
> library(MuMIn)

> domin(weight ~ 1, 
  lmer, 
  list(\(x) list(R2m = MuMIn::r.squaredGLMM(x)[[1]]), "R2m"), 
  data = ChickWeight, 
  sets = list("Time + Time:Diet", "Diet + Time:Diet"), 
  consmodel = "(1 | Chick)")

Overall Fit Statistic:      0.765202 
Constant Model Fit Statistic:  0 

General Dominance Statistics:
     General Dominance Standardized Ranks
set1         0.3859209    0.5043386     1
set2         0.3792811    0.4956614     2

Conditional Dominance Statistics:
        IVs: 1        IVs: 2
set1 0.7718418 -1.838085e-12
set2 0.7652020 -6.639834e-03

Complete Dominance Designations:
             Dmnated?set1 Dmnated?set2
Dmnates?set1           NA         TRUE
Dmnates?set2        FALSE           NA

Components of sets:
set1 : Time + Time:Diet 
set2 : Diet + Time:Diet
```

The effect of `Time` slightly edges out `Diet` - however, they are difficult to separate given the interaction and really probably shouldn't be evaluated in this fashion as the interaction is a component of each and biased without both first order terms in the model (which is why the "IVs: 2" results in the "Conditional Dominance Statistics" matrix are negative).

A better idea is to remove their interaction to clearly distinguish between the two.  If the interaction is not estimated, their effects are much clearer:

```
> domin(weight ~ Time + Diet, 
  lmer, 
  list(\(x) list(R2m = MuMIn::r.squaredGLMM(x)[[1]]), "R2m"), 
  data = ChickWeight, 
  consmodel = "(1 | Chick)")

Overall Fit Statistic:      0.7382927 
Constant Model Fit Statistic:  0 

General Dominance Statistics:
     General Dominance Standardized Ranks
Time        0.68952943   0.93395131     1
Diet        0.04876327   0.06604869     2

Conditional Dominance Statistics:
        IVs: 1     IVs: 2
Time 0.6962558 0.68280310
Diet 0.0554896 0.04203694

Complete Dominance Designations:
             Dmnated?Time Dmnated?Diet
Dmnates?Time           NA         TRUE
Dmnates?Diet        FALSE           NA
```

This much more clearly favors `Time` and only loses a bit of predictive utility.  The interaction can be built-in as a separate predictor if desired using [LeBreton, Tonidandel, and Krasikova's (2013)](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/1094428113481065) residualization method, most likely with a separate residual for each included level of `Diet`.